# Quickly apply multiple filters to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I am trying to filter this dataframe:

```
     ID  fallowDeer     woodland       fox         rabbits
     1         0.0     4.056649      2.210927      31.150451
     2         0.0     2.267544      1.380185      38.631221
     3         0.0     5.602904      1.201781      4.124286
     4         0.0     7.377308      7.834358      25.911328
     5         0.0     2.129115      1.564075      3.931565
     6         0.0     5.988451      1.699852      32.915730
     7         0.0     1.427553      3.586585      7.444735
     8         0.0     9.857577      8.709137      34.004470
     9         0.0     7.468365      1.317117      38.440278
    10         0.0     3.902134      4.112038      22.427969
```

To keep only those rows where each species is between the minimum and maximum values shown below (these are series):

**Minimum values**

```
fallowDeer        0
woodland          1
fox               3
rabbits           10
```

**Maximum values**

```
fallowDeer        0
woodland          4
fox               6
rabbits           20
```

This code works:

```
accepted_simulations = df[(df['fallowDeer'] <= max_values['fallowDeer']) & (df['fallowDeer'] >= min_values['fallowDeer']) & (df['woodland'] <= max_values['woodland']) & (df['woodland'] >= min_values['woodland']) & (df['fox'] <= max_values['fox']) & (df['fox'] >= min_values['fox']) & (df['rabbits'] <= max_values['rabbits']) & (df['rabbits'] >= min_values['rabbits'])]
```

However, I am going to be adding many more species/columns in the future, and would like to avoid having to manually check each species against the min/max as I've done here. Is there a way to quickly compare each species to the min/max and filter the dataframe, without having to manually check each one?

Comment: Your minimum and maximum values are a dictionary right? Can you provide it as such in your example as well

Answer (score 0):

You can compare all columns together, if `min_values` and `max_values` are `Series` with [`Index.intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html) for get columns names by index of minimal and maximal values and compared by [`DataFrame.le`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.le.html) and 
[`DataFrame.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ge.html):

```
c1 = df.columns.intersection(min_values.index)
m1 = df[c1].ge(min_values.loc[c1])
print (m1)
   fallowDeer  woodland    fox  rabbits
0        True      True  False     True
1        True     False  False     True
2        True      True  False    False
3        True      True   True     True
4        True     False  False    False
5        True      True  False     True
6        True     False  False    False
7        True      True   True     True
8        True      True  False     True
9        True     False  False     True

c2 = df.columns.intersection(max_values.index)
m2 = df[c2].le(max_values.loc[c2])
print (m2)
   fallowDeer  woodland    fox  rabbits
0        True     False   True    False
1        True     False   True    False
2        True     False   True     True
3        True     False  False    False
4        True     False   True     True
5        True     False   True    False
6        True     False  False     True
7        True     False  False    False
8        True     False   True    False
9        True     False  False    False
```

Then is possible chain both masks:

```
m = m1 & m2
print (m)
   fallowDeer  woodland    fox  rabbits
0        True     False  False    False
1        True     False  False    False
2        True     False  False    False
3        True     False  False    False
4        True     False  False    False
5        True     False  False    False
6        True     False  False    False
7        True     False  False    False
8        True     False  False    False
9        True     False  False    False
```

Last for filter if `True` in all rows of mask use [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
accepted_simulations  = df[m.all(axis=1)]
print (accepted_simulations)

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [ID, fallowDeer, woodland, fox, rabbits]
Index: []
```

Comment: You should specify that you used a dictionary for `min_values` and `max_values`